# Selenium cant use the find_element_by_css_selector()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**The Situation:**

Firstly I would like to say that am new to selenium and decided to pick it up to practice some python. I am currently following a tutorial online and decided to make a youtube bot.

**The Code:**

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
    import time
    import random
    
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
    
    def login_with_username_and_password(browser, username, password):
        # FILL UP THE LOGIN FORM
        email_input = browser.find_elements('input[type=email]')
    
        email = username
        for letter in email:
            email_input.send_keys(letter)
            wait_time = random.randint(0,1000)/1000
            time.sleep(wait_time)
    
        next_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
        time.sleep(2)
        next_button[2].click()
        time.sleep(2)
    
        password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=password]')
        password = password
        for letter in password:
            password_input.send_keys(letter)
            wait_time = random.randint(0,1000)/1000
            time.sleep(wait_time)
    
        next_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
        time.sleep(2)
        next_button[1].click()
    
        confirm_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[role=button]")
        time.sleep(2)
        if(len(confirm_button)>0):
            confirm_button[1].click()
    
    def click_on_agree_and_signin(browser):
        # agree_button= browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
        # time.sleep(2)
        # agree_button.click()
    
        signin_buttons= browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".signin")
        time.sleep(6) # Wait longer so the message pops up
        while(len(signin_buttons)== 0):
            signin_buttons= browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".signin")
            time.sleep(1)
    
        signin_buttons[0].click()
    
    def enter_search_term(browser,search_term):
        # Enter text on the search term
        search_input = browser.find_element_by_id("search")
        for letter in search_term:
            search_input.send_keys(letter)
            wait_time = random.randint(0,1000)/1000
            time.sleep(wait_time)
    
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    def enter_comment(browser, comment):
        comment_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-comment-simplebox-renderer")
    
        entering_comment_actions = ActionChains(browser)
    
        entering_comment_actions.move_to_element(comment_input)
        entering_comment_actions.click()
    
        for letter in comment:
            entering_comment_actions.send_keys(letter)
            wait_time = random.randint(0,1000)/1000
            entering_comment_actions.pause(wait_time)
    
        entering_comment_actions.perform()
    
        time.sleep(1)
    
        send_comment_button = browser.find_element_by_id("submit-button")
        send_comment_button.click()
    
    ###########################################
    #             BOT STARTS HERE             #
    ###########################################
    
    
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    all_search_terms = ['online marketing']
    
    # Click Agree and Sing In
    click_on_agree_and_signin(driver)
    
    # Sign In
    login_with_username_and_password(driver, "hey289895@gmail.com", "-1qa2ws3ed4rf-")
    for search_term in all_search_terms:
        enter_search_term(driver, search_term)
        time.sleep(2)
    
        thumbnails = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-video-renderer")
    
        for index in range(1, 6):
            thumbnails[index].click()
            time.sleep(6)
            enter_comment(driver, "love it")
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            thumbnails = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ytd-video-renderer")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
```

**The Problem:**
When Running this code it produces an error related to the find_element_by_css_selector method. [Most frequently during the sign in phase as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9JCG.png).

**The Question:**

Can anybody explain what is going on here and where I am going wrong, as well as how I can fix this please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: it is `warning` that `find_elements_by_...` are deprecated and probably you have to use `find_elements(BY...., )`. It seems they change this in the newest version of Selenium because I have version `3.141.0` and it still can use `find_elements_by_...`. You can check your version with `print(selenium.__version__)`

Answer (score 2):

First: it is only `warning`, not `error`.

---

In my version `3.141.0` I can use both methods

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Firefox()

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(...)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(...)
# etc.
```

and

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Firefox()

driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...)
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ...)
# etc.
```

but it seems they plan to remove functions `find_elements_by_...` in the future (in versions `4.x`) and now `find_elements_by_...` still works but it shows `warning` that you should use second method `find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...)`.

You could use module `warnings` to hide these warnings but better start using only second method.

---

**BTW:**

In source code for [find_elements_by_css_selector](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) you can see it runs `warning.warn(...)` and next it runs `find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...)`

---

To check what version you use

```
import selenium

print(selenium.__version__)
```